# How to interpret hourly rate data given in one miniute intervals

Tags: time-series, aggregation, transform

I have time series data on natural gas flow, which is in units of "tonnes/hour". But the data are given in one minute intervals (each row represents a single minute of time duration). Here is a sample:

```
   DateTime                 Flow_t_h
1: 2018-11-01 08:00:00      100.1
2: 2018-11-01 08:01:00      110.3
3: 2018-11-01 08:02:00      112.4
4: 2018-11-01 08:03:00      109.3
5: 2018-11-01 08:04:00      105.1
6: 2018-11-01 08:05:00      100.0
```

I'm not sure how to interpret a one minute sample from an hourly rate. Does that make the rate tonnes/minute? Or one-minute's worth of tonnes/hour?

If I aggregate the minute data into hours (i.e. sum of each 60 minute period), is it still tonnes/hour?

If I aggregate to days (i.e. sum of each 1440 minute period), would it be tonnes/day?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a familiar analogy will help.  Suppose your "Flow_t_h" is really a vehicle's speed in kilometers per hour, as recorded minute by minute.  Does that make its speed kilometers per minute?  Or one-minute's worth of kilometers per hour?  What will you aggregate: average speed or total distance traveled?  Is there any question in your mind, in this analogous situation, about what makes sense or what numerical calculations to carry out?  If not, you have your answers.

Comment: @whuber: Right now I see that as this is a rate, I would take the mean, not the sum. Thanks!